# django orm filters and nested Prefetch

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to get all users who have instances with the status of running or creating, and get instances for these users with the same filter, my query looks like

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(
            Q(testinstance__status=TestInstance.RUNNING) |
            Q(testinstance__status=TestInstance.CREATING)
        ).order_by('first_name').prefetch_related(Prefetch(
            'testinstance_set',
            queryset=TestInstance.objects.filter(
                Q(status=TestInstance.RUNNING) | Q(status=TestInstance.CREATING)
            ).order_by('-started_at')
        )).distinct()
```

models:

```
class TestInstance(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Can I somehow avoid duplicate filters ?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that though? You do realize that the prefetch is done in a separate query right? So the filter would need to be there, no way around that.

Comment: I find it strange that I need to repeat the filter twice, and I think there is a better solution

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work without the duplicate filter? `prefetch_related` should only fetch related objects according matching the top queryset anyway.

Comment: @Agate no, what prefetch related does is that after the base queryset is fetched it uses the ids of those instances and then makes a query to fetch all instances related to those ids (and then maps the relationship in python). So, no that filter cannot be skipped.